# R Xpath getNodeSet does not handle utf-8 in Windows?

Tags: xml, r, windows, xpath, utf-8

**Update**: Ok, it seems to be a windows-specific issue. More particularly, the windows locale keyboard that supports non-latin (in this case diacritic) characters for other commands in R, does not support them in Xpath getNodeSet.

So the following windows keyboard-specific locale does not work

```
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Estonian_Estonia.1257;LC_CTYPE=Estonian_Estonia.1257;
    LC_MONETARY=Estonian_Estonia.1257;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Estonian_Estonia.1257"
```

The same query in an utf-8 keyboard does in Ubuntu 14.04 work. Such as the following:

```
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_CTYPE=et_EE.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=et_EE.UTF-8;
     LC_COLLATE=et_EE.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=et_EE.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;
     LC_PAPER=et_EE.UTF-8;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;
     LC_MEASUREMENT=et_EE.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"
```

Seems like Xpath may be processing the characters differently from common R commands, such as subsetting a dataframe. I doubt there is an easy solution for this, but if anyone can specify the problem or offer the solution it will be amazing.

**The problem as stated**:

Say I have a simple xml file with utf-8 encoding.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <doc>
  <!-- A comment -->
  <a xmlns:ns="http://www.omegahat.org">
    <b>utf-8-non
    </b>
    <b>utf-8-hää
    </b>
</a>
</doc>
```

I read it with xmlParse:

```
library(XML) 
doc = xmlParse("konv_korpus/TEI/let_tokenized/new.xml")
```

When I look for latin characters:

```
getNodeSet(doc, "/doc//b[starts-with(.,'utf-8')]")
```

I get a list including "utf-8-hää" in them.

```
[[1]]
<b>utf-8-non
    </b> 

[[2]]
<b>utf-8-hää
    </b> 

attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLNodeSet"
```

But when I look for non-latin characters:

```
getNodeSet(doc, "/doc//b[starts-with(.,'utf-8-hää')]")
```

I get empty list as a result.

```
list()
attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLNodeSet"
```

Anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: What's `doc2`? `getNodeSet(doc, "/doc//b[starts-with(.,'utf-8-hää')]")` works fine on my OS X 10.11 / R 3.2.2 system

Comment: Sorry, doc2 was an accident on cleaning up for the post. The only difference between the lines is in presence or lack of "-hää". Even with "-h" the search is successful, but not with "-hä". I guess it may be a Windows thing then. Working on Windows 10 x64 R 3.2.1. Maybe updating R could help?

Comment: Updated R to 3.2.2. and all the packages, no luck in getting it to work thus far.

Comment: May be a rather deep Windows issue of commands encoding non-standard characters in different ways. Worked in Ubuntu 14.04 too as in OS X, thanks for the tip!